# Variables in alias tag showing in link level reporting

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to include a couple of variables within a Concat inside an Alias tag and I am not seeing the expected string in "LinkName" reporting values but rather the variable names.

So I get something like this:
SomeText',@Version,'-',@CampaignDate,'-',SomeMoreText

Is there any workaround for this? I was hoping that using the AmpScript function called Output and wrapping that around the Concat might work but so far no luck there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had this problem, but I think I've found a less painful solution. You don't have to put the entire anchor tag into Concat - just the alias attribute and value.

So instead of trying to put this in your HTML:

```
alias="%%=v(@title)=%%"
```

try this - make sure you leave spaces either side of it:

```
%%=v(@alias)=%%
```

Then ensure you've got this set somewhere (you'll need to set @title too) - in my case I have a loop that sets this for each row:

```
Set @alias = Concat('alias="', @title, '" ')
```

Seems to work in a quick test email.

Comment: You could also do this instead of creating another variable: `<a href="#" %%=concat("alias='",@title,"' ")=%%>whee</a>`

Answer (score 4):

AMPScript variables will not get evaluated in alias tags, unfortunately (confirmed by SFMC Support).  Best thing to do is not use the `linkName` in your web-analytics connector or always use static values for aliases.

You can work around it by building the entire anchor tag -- href, alias and all --in AMPScript using `concat()`, which is a royal pain.

Comment: Well that bleeping stinks, but at least confirms what I had found. :-) Thanks for the info Adam!

Comment: ^^^ Might be my all time favorite comment here.

Comment: Is this still the case? Documentation shows Ampscript in the alias. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/dynamicLinkNames.htm

Comment: I believe so. Just ran across it again last week.

Comment: Even if it works for 100 uniques its problematic for triggered sends.

Comment: Interesting. We have variables building dynamic alias values and the problem we are seeing is some render correctly while others are the full URL, even for the same link. Someone did bring up the 100 unique url to alias combinations. I can't find any documentation around this.