# Variables in alias tag

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

i have a loop that sets alias attribute for each row

```
%%[
var @title_value, @url_value
var @alias_attr
set @alias_attr = concat("alias","=",'"',@title_value,'"')
]%%
```

when i inspect the link, seeing below :

```
<a  
href="%%=RedirectTo(@url_value)=%%" 
%%=v(@alias_attr)=%% 
conversion="true">
    <strong> %%=v(@title_value)=%% </strong>
</a>
```

from email i click the above link, but displays in the browser url :
`http://.../life-science-applications-UVVIS-spectroscopy.html?j=1261192&e=generic@mt.com&l=467_HTML&u=33618321&mid=6175969&jb=1&cmp=em-mt_1261192&et_cid=em-mt_1261192&et_rid=32594728&Linkid=%%%3dRedirectTo(%40title_value)%3d%%%3fj%3d%%jobid%%%26e%3d%%EmailAddr_%%%26l%3d%%List_%%%26u%3d33618321%26mid%3d%%MemberID%%%26jb%3d1%26cmp%3dem-mt_%%jobid%%%%%3dIIF(EMPTY(identifier7)%2c%22%22%2cConcat(%22%7c%22%2cidentifier7))%3d%%`

the linkid is not properly evaluated

what could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, AMPScript in the link alias tags will not get evaluated in the Web Analytics Connector string.

I've been around-and-around with SFMC Support about this.  It's one of those little SFMC annoyances that's been around for years.

Previously discussed here: [Variables in Alias Showing in Link Level Reporting](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/76773/variables-in-alias-tag-showing-in-link-level-reporting/76793#76793)

Comment: Hi Adam, 
Even tried to generate the entire to generate the entire html tag but the problem i was facing is RedirectTo was getting evaluated properly.

When the links is clicked from email it was not getting tracked, i guess because of RedirectTo was evaluated.